# Proving that there is no values of z such that cosz = isinz

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Here is my attempt:

Assume there are values of $z$ such that $\cos z = i \sin(z)$

Then

$\cos(z) = \dfrac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$

and

$i\sin(z) = \dfrac{i(e^{iz} - e^{-iz})}{2i}$

and so after doing some algebra we get

$4e^{-iz} = 0$

and this will never happen, since e^whatever will never be zero , that's a contradiction and hence there are no values of $z$ such that $\cos(z) = i\sin(z)$

Comment: Or simply $\cos z-i\sin z=e^{-iz}\ne0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's one way to do it, and is correct.

Alternative approach: If $\cos{z} = i \sin{z}$, then

$$\cos^2{z} + \sin^2{z} = -\sin^2{z} + \sin^2{z} = 0$$

contradicting that $\cos^2{z} + \sin^2{z} = 1$.